# Why are stdin and stdout considered files in C?

Tags: c, stdout, stdin

For example, the `stdio.h` library has some functions that require a `FILE *` argument but accept `stdin` for user input from a terminal.

Comment: What would *you* consider them?

Comment: Because `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are `FILE *`s?

Comment: *When I see a bird that walks like a duck and swims like a duck and quacks like a duck, I call that bird a duck.*

Comment: It would be more correct to say that `stdin`, `stdout`, and `stderr` are "I/O streams" rather than files.

Comment: They are standards that were created for portability.

Comment: As to the origion of the wording: a file is per definition a line of things one behind another[1] - in this case an array of bytes. That's why even a block of memory sometimes is called a memory file. [1] http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/file#file-2

Comment: Everything is a file in Unix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C `stdio` functions operate on *streams*, not files.  As far as your code is concerned, a stream is simply a consumer (output stream) or producer (input stream) of bytes.

A stream may be associated with a file on disk.  It may also be associated with a terminal.  Or a printer.  Or a network socket.  Or anything else that you might want to communicate with.  A stream is an *abstraction* of anything that can read or write a string of bytes.

`stdin` and `stdout` (along with `stderr`) are predefined `FILE *` objects which normally refer to your console, although you can override that either at the command line or within your code.

Answer (score 0):

The `stdin` and `stdout` are nothing more than the pointers of the file for the standard input and output. due to the fact that you can change these within your code or with the Command Prompt these can't be pointing to an actual input because then you would not be able to change it.

The `stdin` and`stdio` simply take the information from the files where the `standard output` or `standard input` read from or write to. this way it is a lot easier to change it using commands and codes.